# using setInterval() to get a new time every 2 seconds. The new time is 30 seconds ahead of now

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, setinterval

First I set the `div.test`'s text to a string one minute in the future.Then every 2 seconds I want that time to increase every 30 seconds. right now the time increase 2 seconds every 2 seconds. (I think on the first Interval is the exception because only that increases 30 seconds.) I want the seconds part of the text to increase by 30 seconds every 2 second Interval.

```js
function getStringFormat(d) {
  function getFullDay(d) {
    var weekday = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
    return weekday[d.getDay()];
  }

  function getFullMonth(d) {
    var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
    return months[d.getMonth()]
  }
  return getFullDay(d) + ", " + getFullMonth(d) + " " + d.getDate() + ", " + d.getFullYear() + " " + d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds()
}

//first deadline
function getNewFutureTime(t) {
  return getStringFormat(new Date(new Date().getTime() + t * 1000))
    // oned
}
$(".test").html(getNewFutureTime(60));
setInterval(function() {
  $(".test").html(getNewFutureTime(30));
}, 2 * 1000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Your `getNewFutureTime` output is based on the *current actual time*, not the currently-displayed future time. You keep asking for a time 30 seconds from *right now*.

Comment: I thought if i called `getNewFutureTime` with the 30 param it will give me a new 30 seconds because in the func Im creating a new date.Is a solution to get the text inside setInterval function then make that into a Date obj and add 30 seconds then to  output inside setInterval?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a new date every time you run getNewFutureTime, you should grab the current time at the start of the code and just increment that by 30 every 2 seconds.

```
var futureDate = new Date();

        function getStringFormat(d){
            function getFullDay(d){
                var weekday = ["Sunday", "Monday","Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
                return weekday[d.getDay()];
            }

            function getFullMonth(d){
                var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
                return months[d.getMonth()]
            }
            return getFullDay(d) +", " + getFullMonth(d) +" "+ d.getDate() + ", " + d.getFullYear() + " " +  d.getHours()+":"+ d.getMinutes() +":" + d.getSeconds()
        }

        //first deadline
        function getNewFutureTime(t){
            futureDate.setTime(futureDate.getTime() + t * 1000);
            return getStringFormat(futureDate)
            // oned
        }
        $(".test").html(getNewFutureTime(60));
        setInterval(function(){
            $(".test").html(getNewFutureTime(30));
        }, 2 * 1000)
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2yn3bq4g/2/)

Comment: You're right, using setTime is better than creating a new date there.  Thanks.